# How to select a row of data with multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that has a column that contains following data:

```
EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS
```

Semicolons separate the employers, up to 5, and commas separate the `EmployerName` and Employer address.

I need to select the row and display as follows:

```
EMPNAME1 EMPADDRESS1 EMPNAME2 EMPADDRESS2 EMPNAME3 EMPADDRESS3.....
```

Comment: Please share the SQL that you attempted to use.

Comment: You should make more clear what you are asking and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would write a specific splitstring function that suites your need and use it in a select on that source table. Have a look at CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING(). Here is an quickly grabbed example that could make things clear: [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string#10914602) 
and further information on how to write a tsql function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

No code in question, no code in answer, hope it helps =)

Comment: Good afternoon Jan. I didn't realise it at first, but I feel that my answer is an extension to your answer. Would you like me to add my code to your answer? Let me know

Comment: No way! Your answer took much more effort than mine, so you should "harvest the laurels" if there ever will be any. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Split function with the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.split (    

    --DECLARE
          @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @Character CHAR(1)

) RETURNS @Output TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1

      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
          BEGIN
                SET @Input = @Input + @Character

          END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
          BEGIN
                SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

                INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

                SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))

          END

      RETURN

END
GO
```

To make the function available to the whole server, run the above code.

Once created, the function can be referenced in a query in a similar way to how a table is referenced, as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item)) AS EmployeeId, 
    SUBSTRING(Item, 0, CHARINDEX (',', Item)) AS EmployeeName,
    SUBSTRING(Item, CHARINDEX (',', Item) + 1,LEN(Item)) AS EmployeeAddress
FROM 
    dbo.split('EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS', ';') AS Employee
```

The above query will display your data in a neat table.

Using this as a base, I created the following procedure, which eccepts a single NVARCHAR input parameter, and displays the columns in the way that you requested:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Employee(

    --DECLARE
            @Input NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS'

) AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item)) AS EmployeeId, 
        SUBSTRING(Item, 0, CHARINDEX (',', Item)) AS EmployeeName,
        SUBSTRING(Item, CHARINDEX (',', Item) + 1,LEN(Item)) AS EmployeeAddress
    INTO #Employees
    FROM 
        dbo.split(@Input, ';') AS Employee


    SELECT
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 1) AS EmpName1,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeAddress FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 1) AS EmpAddress1,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 2) AS EmpName2,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeAddress FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 2) AS EmpAddress2,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 3) AS EmpName3,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeAddress FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 3) AS EmpAddress3,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 4) AS EmpName4,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeAddress FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 4) AS EmpAddress4,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 5) AS EmpName5,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeAddress FROM #Employees WHERE EmployeeId = 5) AS EmpAddress5

    DROP TABLE #Employees

END
```

The way the procedure works is as follows:

- Save the table to a temporary table named #Employees.
- Select the top 5 Employees as a single row.
- Drop the temporary table.

Use the procedure in the following way:

```
exec Employee 'EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS;EMPLOYER-NAME,EMPADDRESS'
```